# Select maximum value in a list and the attributes related with that value

Tags: python, list, optimization, coding-style

I am looking for a way to select the major value in a list of numbers in order to get the attributes.

```
data
[(14549.020163184512, 58.9615170298556),
 (18235.00848249135, 39.73350448334156),
 (12577.353023695543, 37.6940001866714)]
```

I wish to extract (18235.00848249135, 39.73350448334156) in order to have 39.73350448334156. The previous list (data) is derived from a a empty list data=[]. Is it the list the best format to store data in a loop?

Comment: to be clear, you have a list of tuples, you want to get the tuple with the highest first value, and extract its second value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it by :

`max(data)[1]`

since tuples will be compared by the first element by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
max(data)[1]
```

Sorting a tuple sorts according to the first elements, then the second. It means `max(data)` sorts according to the first element.

`[1]` returns then the second element from the "maximal" object.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, it seems easy or what?)
max(a)[1] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually sort on any attribute of the list. You can use [itemgetter](http://www.dr-chuck.com/csev-blog/2010/01/fun-python-syntax-operator-itemgetter-sorted-and-lambda-functions-oh-my/). Another way to sort would be to use a definitive compare functions (when you might need multiple levels of itemgetter, so the below code is more readable).

```
dist = ((1, {'a':1}), (7, {'a': 99}), (-1, {'a':99}))

def my_cmp(x, y):
    tmp = cmp(x[1][a], y[1][a])
    if tmp==0:
        return (-1 * cmp(x[0], y[0]))
    else: return tmp

sorted = dist.sort(cmp=my_cmp) # sorts first descending on attr "a" of the second item, then sorts ascending on first item
```